# Does this questions have a Verb?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-meaning

Consider the sentence in image - Hence his emphatic insistence "on the importance of genius and the necessity of allowing it to unfold itself freely both in thought and practice," and his advocacy of such measures as a second vote for university graduates.

Does this sentence have a Verb? Why can't I see it?
Can someone please explain to me the meaning of "Hence" here if it is used as a Verb? Or can anyone make a stripped-down version of this sentence for me to understand please?

[image]

Comment: First hit on a Google search for *hence without verb* https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hence-sentence-with-a-verb-verb-or-no-verb.3067885/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no verb in that phrase. I've seen expressions like this before and the meaning is clear enough.  A simpler example

> John didn't clean his boots.  Hence the mud.

That example looks more like spoken English, and would be understood to mean "There is mud on the boots".  I'm slightly surprised to see a construction like this in a text book, but alternatives would seem wordy and no more clear, and much harder to incorporate the quote unchanged.

If you rewrote this to use "insist" as a verb you would need to paraphrase the quotation.

> He insisted that genius was important and it was neccessary allow it to unfold...

But it is good scholarship to keep the quote unchanged, which required the use of the slightly informal construction.  I doubt the authors were considering anybody using this text as an English Learning exercise when they wrote it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers first. I'm not learning English bu I have to translate this text into my own language for study purposes.